# How to read multiple values at one time as an input to single variable in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, record, procedure

Could you help me to pass the input values (at execution time: i mean to enter multiple values for single variable at once).

Here is my code for which i am giving one input at a time either hard coded input or single input at time.

```
declare
  type TEmpRec is record (
    EmployeeID EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
    LastName   EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE
  );
  type TEmpList is table of TEmpRec;
  vEmpList TEmpList;
  ---------
  function EmpRec(pEmployeeID EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
                  pLastName  EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE default null) return TEmpRec is
  -- Effective "Record constructor"
    vResult TEmpRec;
  begin
    vResult.EmployeeID := pEmployeeID;
    vResult.LastName  := pLastName;
    return vResult;
  end;
  ---------
  procedure SearchRecs(pEmpList in out nocopy TEmpList) is    -- Nocopy is a hint to pass by reference (pointer, so small) rather than value (actual contents, so big)
    vIndex PLS_integer;
  begin
    if pEmpList is not null then
      vIndex := pEmpList.First;
      while vIndex is not null -- The "while" approach can be used on sparse collections (where items have been deleted)
      loop
        begin
          select LAST_NAME
          into  pEmpList(vIndex).LastName
          from  EMPLOYEES
          where  EMPLOYEE_ID = pEmpList(vIndex).EmployeeID;
        exception
          when NO_DATA_FOUND then
            pEmpList(vIndex).LastName := 'F'||pEmpList(vIndex).EmployeeID;
        end;
        vIndex := pEmpList.Next(vIndex);
      end loop;
    end if;
  end;
  ---------
  procedure OutputRecs(pEmpList TEmpList) is
    vIndex PLS_integer;
  begin
    if pEmpList is not null then
      vIndex := pEmpList.First;
      while vIndex is not null
      loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'pEmpList(' || vIndex ||') = '|| pEmpList(vIndex).EmployeeID||', '|| pEmpList(vIndex).LastName);
        vIndex := pEmpList.Next(vIndex);
      end loop;
    end if;
  end;
begin
  vEmpList := TEmpList(EmpRec(100),
                       EmpRec( 34),
                       EmpRec(104),
                       EmpRec(110));
  SearchRecs(vEmpList);
  OutputRecs(vEmpList);
end;
/
```

Above program takes input value one at time.
However, i tried as below but unable to succeed.

i tried to give input from console at once like (100,34,104,100) in place of either hard coding the input (or) giving one input at time.

**Snippet in DECLARE section:**

```
declare
  type TEmpRec is record (
    EmployeeID EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
    LastName   EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE
  );
  type TEmpList is table of TEmpRec;
  v_input TEmpList := TEmpList(&v_input); -- to read multiple input at once
  vEmpList TEmpList;
```

**In the final BEGIN section:**

```
BEGIN
FOR j IN v_input.FIRST .. v_input.LAST LOOP
  vEmpList := TEmpList(EmpRec(v_input(j).EmployeeID)); --to assign input values to vEmptList

  SearchRecs(vEmpList);
  OutputRecs(vEmpList);
end loop;
end;
/
```

**Error in DECLARE section:**
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEMPLIST'
**Error in LAST BEGIN section:**
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed

**As an example:** at time, i am able to read multiple input values for same variable but i am unable to pass this as an input but  unable to figure out how can make this as an input my main program.

```
DECLARE
TYPE t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
ORDERS t := t(&ORDERS);
BEGIN
FOR j IN ORDERS.FIRST .. ORDERS.LAST LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(ORDERS(j));
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Output:
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Enter value for orders: 321,153,678

321
153
678

Thank You.

Comment: `TEmpRec` is a plain PL/SQL record type, so it doesn't have a constructor. If you want a constructor you'll need to create an object type. If you want a more detailed answer, an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make the issue clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since You have a collection of  `record` variable, you  need to pass `employee_ids` and employee `last_names` separately. How are you planning to pass them in a single shot?.
 Here is a sample script which accomplishes something you want with 2 inputs for 3 collection elements.

First,  create a collection `TYPE`  and a `PIPELINED function` to convert comma separated values into `Collections` - `f_convert2`.

```
CREATE TYPE test_type AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_convert2(p_list IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN test_type
PIPELINED
AS
  l_string       LONG := p_list || ',';
  l_comma_index  PLS_INTEGER;
  l_index        PLS_INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    l_comma_index := INSTR(l_string, ',', l_index);
    EXIT WHEN l_comma_index = 0;
    PIPE ROW ( SUBSTR(l_string, l_index, l_comma_index - l_index) );
    l_index := l_comma_index + 1;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END f_convert2;
/
```

Then in your anonymous blocks pass values for employee_ids and last_name separately.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    TYPE temprec IS RECORD ( employeeid    employees.employee_id%TYPE,
    lastname      employees.last_name%TYPE );
    TYPE templist IS
        TABLE OF temprec;
    vemplist      templist;
    v_no_of_rec   NUMBER := 10;

    v_empl_ids VARCHAR2(100) := '&empl_ids'; 
    v_empl_lnames VARCHAR2(100) := '&empl_lnames'; 
BEGIN
SELECT employee_id,last_name
    BULK COLLECT
INTO
    vemplist
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROWNUM rn,
            column_value employee_id
        FROM
            TABLE ( f_convert2(v_empl_ids) )
    ) a
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            ROWNUM rn,
            column_value last_name
        FROM
            TABLE ( f_convert2(v_empl_lnames) )
    ) b ON a.rn = b.rn;

        FOR i in 1..vemplist.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vemplist(i).employeeid || '  ' ||vemplist(i).lastname);
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Instead of simple JOIN above if you use `OUTER JOIN` ( `FULL` or `LEFT` ), you can handle missing values without writing logic to check each value.

Comment: Thanks Kaushik. I will try this. Actually I don't only READ Access to my database and I can only write Anonymous blocks and my input is just employee ID (multiple values at one time)

Comment: In that case, you can have the TYPE and function defined with the declare.

Comment: When i tried above code, i encountered following error. PLS-00231: function 'F_CONVERT2' may not be used in SQL

Comment: Check this link. You cannot call a function defined in anonymous block from sql.  You need to create the function object.That's how we all do it generally.  However it is possible in 12c using with clause.   Refer https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9525551800346153671 . An alternative would be to use the whole block of code in the function in you code.